# Rails VS Django questions

Tags: python, ruby-on-rails, ruby, django

Due to the pains **deploying** Rails apps I'm looking into learning Python and Django. I love many features of Rails, but deployment is just very troublesome.

Before taking the time-consuming enterprise of learning Python and Django there are some questions I need to consider.

1. Does Django has Rails-like-commands such as `rails g migration`?
2. Does Django has an app console such as `rails console`?
3. Does Python has a console such as `irb`?
4. Does Python has RubyGems-like packages such as Devise, CanCan, Event Calendar, Carrierwave, etc?
5. Are Django app deployments as painful as Rails'?

I might have other questions but these are the ones I can think of now. Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried googling answers to these questions?

Comment: Yes, Yes, Yes, Yes, No

Comment: Don't ask multiple questions in one post. How are we supposed to vote on correct answers? Some of your questions are also highly subjective and/or solicit debate and opinion, instead of concrete answers.

Comment: Only question 5 could solicit debate and opinion. The other ones are concrete questions.

Answer (score 3):

Here are some suggestions:

1. [Django south](http://south.aeracode.org/)
2. [Django shell](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/django-admin/#shell)
3. Yes
4. There are plenty of packages out there find [here](https://pypi.python.org/pypi?%3aaction=index). Use [pip](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pip) or [easy-install](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/setuptools) to install them or manually
5. No. I found it easy to deploy not sure about other opinions.

Comment: Python has a console too .

Comment: Yeah i know. so answer is Yes.

Answer (score 1):

1. Yes, but it is not a part of Django. It's a separate package named South.
2. Yes.
3. Yes.
4. There are plenty of packages.
5. No. Django app deployments are not as painful as Rails'. They are much more painful.